# Product page edit error "there is error processing your request"

Tags: magento-1.9, product

i have following concern, as whenever i try to open the product to edit in  admin panel it showing me the following error, as attached

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide this log report instead of sceenshot? b'coz it help us better to identify this problem you can find this log in `root/var/report`

Comment: my log dir has no file

Comment: Check My answer and provide me updated error

Comment: Error log record number: 559466719540

Comment: Error log record number: 559466719540 and m finding and error log record number in report dir

Comment: remove `var/cache` folder and check again with error

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:110:"Source model "temando/entity_attribute_source_packaging_mode" not found for attribute "temando_packaging_mode"";i:1;s:3222:"#0 /home/tantraxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "t...')

Answer (score 1):

**Cause of error**

Usually, it is caused by calling incompatible classes in themes, extensions or templates, database connectivity issues

Go to magento/var/report and open the file with the Error log record number name i.e 12....... in your case. In that file you can find the complete description of the error.

For log files like system.log and exception.log, go to magento/var/log/

**OR**

You can go to the index.php file in the root of the project. In the file find the line that says:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

put the statement inside the if block outside of the block so that it is seen as:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    }
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

This should show you the error when you try to load the page in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

also go to your `root/errors/` and rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` so that you can get error on your browser screen

Comment: error still coming

Comment: Can you please provide me log?? you can check `var\report` and file with same number shown in screen

Comment: disable `temando` extension from your `etc\module` and try again

Comment: Error log record number: 1117461524571

Comment: Dont give me error number give me error from report folder

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:110:"Source model "temando/entity_attribute_source_packaging_mode" not found for attribute "temando_packaging_mode"";i:1;s:3222:"#0 /home/tantraxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Enti‌​ty/Attribute/Abstrac‌​t.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "t...')

Comment: Have you disable that extension?

Comment: there no extension named temando

Comment: Not exactly same but something like or similiar kind of name extension

Comment: soory but m not getting

Comment: Have you installed Any extension ?

Comment: i have installed many extension

Comment: Bemaged_Contacts Simtech_Searchanise extension

Comment: go to `app/etc` and open `Temando_Temando.xml` file and set `<active>false</active>` and delete `var/cache` folder and try again

Comment: no such file there

Comment: Any other extension from temandao ?

Comment: no there is no  extension from temandao

Comment: How can you get error like `Source model "temando/entity_attribute_source_packaging_mode" ` then ??

Comment: Cm_RedisSession 
Interface_Adminhtml_Default 
Interface_Frontend_Base_Default  
Interface_Frontend_Default 
Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default these extension m using

Comment: Default interface for Install
Lib_Cm 
Lib_Credis 
Lib_Google_Checkout 
Lib_IDNA2 
Lib_Js_Calendar 
Lib_Js_Ext 
Lib_Js_Mage 
Lib_Js_Prototype 
Lib_Js_TinyMCE
Lib_LinLibertineFont 
Lib_Magento 
Lib_Pelago

Comment: Mage_Core_Adminhtml 
Mage_Core_Modules 
Mage_Downloader 
Mage_Locale_en_US 
Magento_Mobile 
Phoenix_Moneybookers 
ASchroder_SMTPPro SendGrid and Google Apps Email support for Magento
Simtech_Searchanise 3.1.1 (stable)   Searchanise Connector Add-on allows you to easily integrate Searchanise rapid search service in your online store. The add-on provides both an admin panel and a customer area widgets.
Bemaged_ContactsCm_RedisSession 
Interface_Adminhtml_Default 
Interface_Frontend_Base_Default  
Interface_Frontend_Default 
Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default all these extension m using

Answer (score 0):

According to error report you mentioned, There is one attribute of product created with custom extension. 
That attribute model is "temando/entity_attribute_source_packaging_mode".
Means this is custom model, and I think currently you have disabled or removed that extension from the system.
So here you have 2 options.

1. Enable or install that extension
2. Remove that attribute from product.